# python pil image to django imagefield convert

Tags: django, upload, thumbnails, python-imaging-library, django-models

I'm uploading an image, image upload and saving it in django model is working just fine. Creating the thumbnail and saving it to temp. location works too. The part that does not work is saving the thumbnail, the file is created and saved but it is an empty file. :/
How can i fix the problem with the missing data.

If someone know how to convert pil image to django model - imagefield without making a tmp saving ... please do tell.

```
def ajax_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        newfile = Image()
        newfile.user = request.user
        file_content = ContentFile(request.raw_post_data)
        file_name = request.GET.get('file')

        newfile.image.save(file_name, file_content)

        # thumbnail creation ==========================================
        path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, newfile.image.url)
        thumb_image = pil_image.open(path)

        # ImageOps compatible mode
        if thumb_image.mode not in ("L", "RGB"):
            thumb_image = thumb_image.convert("RGB")

        thumb_image_fit = ImageOps.fit(thumb_image, (32, 32), pil_image.ANTIALIAS)

        #saving temp file
        tmp_file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'tmp_thumbnail.jpg')
        thumb_image_fit.save(tmp_file_path, 'JPEG', quality=75)

        #opening the tmp file and save it to django model
        thumb_file_data = open(tmp_file_path)
        thumb_file = File(thumb_file_data)

        newfile.thumbnail.save(file_name, thumb_file)
        #===============================================================

        results = {'url': newfile.image.url, 'id': newfile.id, 'width': newfile.image.width, 'height': newfile.image.height}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(results))
    raise Http404
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from PIL import ImageOps, Image as pil_image
import os.path
import json


def ajax_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        newfile = Image()
        newfile.user = request.user
        file_content = ContentFile(request.raw_post_data)
        file_name = request.GET.get('file')

        newfile.image.save(file_name, file_content)
        newfile.thumbnail.save(file_name, file_content)

        #opening and resizing the thumbnail
        path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, newfile.thumbnail.url)
        thumb_file = pil_image.open(path)

        if thumb_file.mode not in ("L", "RGB"):
            thumb_file = thumb_file.convert("RGB")

        thumb_image_fit = ImageOps.fit(thumb_file, (100, 100), pil_image.ANTIALIAS)
        thumb_image_fit.save(path)

        #===============================================================

        results = {
                    'image':
                        {
                            'url': newfile.image.path,
                            'width': newfile.image.width,
                            'height': newfile.image.height
                        },
                    'thumbnal':
                         {
                            'url': newfile.thumbnail.path,
                            'width': newfile.thumbnail.width,
                            'height': newfile.thumbnail.height
                         }
                    }
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(results))
    raise Http404
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save the file and assign its path (relative to MEDIA_ROOT) to destination field manually.

```
thumb_path = 'uploads/1_small.jpg'
thumb_image_fit.save(os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, thumb_path), 'JPEG', quality=75)
newfile.thumbnail = thumb_path
```

Surely you'll need to do all Django's stuff manually - check if the file exists, modify name if it does, and so on.

Comment: I can't test it now but newfile.thumbnail is a ImageField and i don't think 'newfile.thumbnail = thumb_path' will be ok. If i got it right imagefield is saved like this: newfile.thumbnail.save(file_name, thumb_file) (file_name is a string and thumb_file must be a File or ContentFile)

Comment: Yes, `obj.field.save(name, content)` is more correct and oficially documented way. But `FileField` stores only a path in database and allow assigning that path directly. It is undocumented feature, but it works.

Comment: Thanks you, i will remember that for the future.